# Joomla 1.5 creating or editing back end user

Tags: php, plugin, mysql, joomla-1.5

I have a website in joomla , the problem is that when i am creating new back end user (administrator/super user) from joomla user manager it makes an entry in the users table after that it deleted it and it is also not updating any user.
When i am creating the front end user , the front end user creating successfully

Comment: Any errors being shown? Are you using the latest version of the Joomla 1.5 series (1.5.26)?

Comment: No error yes Joomla! 1.5.26 Stable  PHP 5.5.11 mysql 5.5.5-10.0.16-MariaDB  . Microsoft-IIS/7.5 @Lodder

Comment: Joomla may have issue on PHP 5.5. The recommended and most widely used version of PHP with Joomla 1.5 is 5.2